# AForge ColorFiltering different in VS and IPLab

Tags: c#, aforge

I have the following code written in C# using VS2010 and .Net FW 4.0:

```
        AForge.Imaging.Filters.ColorFiltering f1 = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.ColorFiltering();
        f1.FillColor.Color = Color.White ;
        f1.Red = new AForge.IntRange(0, 127);
        f1.Green = new AForge.IntRange(0, 255);
        f1.Blue = new AForge.IntRange(0, 192);
        f1.FillOutsideRange = true;
        f1.ApplyInPlace(bmp);
```

When I execute this code with a particular image, it gives a substantially different result than what is produced when Color Filtering is done in the IP Lab application with the same parameters and the same image.

In IPLab, I am getting an image that is predominately white.  In VS2010, I am getting an image that is predominantly black.  When I change FillOutsideRange to false in VS, I get an image that is barely changed at all.

The image I am processing is of the following PixelFormat:  Format24bppRgb.

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I had to assign the FillColor as follows:

```
 AForge.Imaging.RGB c = new AForge.Imaging.RGB(255, 255, 255);
 f1.FillColor = c;
```

Apparently RGB in C# is different than RGB in AForge.